# Error loading data when using shared_preferences plugin in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Using the shared_preferences plugin I store the data like this:

```dart
// This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
      // assetPath =
      // _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1];
      _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? null : _showAlertDialog();
      _saveData();
    });
  }


  //Saving my data
  Future<void> _saveData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      prefs.setInt('listCount', _listCount);
      prefs.setString('assetPath', assetPath);
      print(_listCount);
      print(assetPath);
    });
  }
```

The console shows the correct values, so I assume that there is no error in this part of the code. Then I want to load the received data in order to continue the game. First getting the data:

```dart
@override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    checkNet();
    _loadData();
  }

  //Loading my data
  Future<void> _loadData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _listCount = (prefs.getInt('listCount') ?? 0);
      assetPath = (prefs.getString('assetPath') ?? "images/01.jpg");
      print(_listCount);
      print(assetPath);
    });
  }
```

Then passing them to the game screen:

```dart
GradientButton(label: 'Continue Game', onTap: () {
                return _internetAvailable == true ?
                {Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Game(
                          listCount: _listCount, assetPath: assetPath ///What I want to pass

                      )),
                    )}
                :
                _internetDialogHandler.showInternetDialog(context);
              }),
```

But every time I get an error:

```dart
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 5
```

At first I thought that the problem was loading the data. But no. Any value of the first argument other than zero produces this error. Why is this happening? And how to fix it? Is the error somewhere else in the code?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';



//My classes
import './my classes.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Example';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
        home: Container(
            child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        // body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
              body: const MainWidget(),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}

// class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
//   const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
class MainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainWidget> createState() => _MainWidgetState();
}


class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {
  CheckUserConnection _checkUserConnection = CheckUserConnection();
  InternetDialogHandler _internetDialogHandler = InternetDialogHandler();
  bool? _internetAvailable;
  int _listCount = 0;
  String assetPath = "";



  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    checkNet();
    _loadData();
  }


  void checkNet() async{
    _internetAvailable = await
    _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();
    setState((){});
  }

  //Loading my data
  Future<void> _loadData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _listCount = (prefs.getInt('listCount') ?? 0);
      assetPath = (prefs.getString('assetPath') ?? "images/01.jpg");
      print(_listCount);
      print(assetPath);
    });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: [
              GradientButton(label: 'New Game', onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Game(
                      listCount: 0, assetPath: "images/04.jpg" ///What I want to pass


                  )),
                );
              }),
              GradientButton(label: 'Continue Game', onTap: () {
                return _internetAvailable == true ?
                {Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Game(
                          listCount: _listCount, assetPath: assetPath ///What I want to pass

                      )),
                    )}
                :
                _internetDialogHandler.showInternetDialog(context);
              }),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              GradientButton(label: 'Back Button', onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const BackRoute()),
                );



                // print('Button 1');



              }),
              GradientButton(label: 'Button 2', onTap: () {print('Button 2');}),
              GradientButton(label: 'Internet', onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const InternetRoute()),
                );
              }),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


//Class for a gradient button
class GradientButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientButton({Key? key, required this.label, required this.onTap}) : super(key: key);
  final String label;
  final Function onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => onTap(),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 8),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[
                Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                Color(0xFF1976D2),
                Color(0xFF42A5F5),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(label, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, decoration: TextDecoration.none),),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


//Game
class Game extends StatefulWidget {
  const Game({Key? key, required this.listCount, required this.assetPath}) : super(key: key);
  final int listCount;
  final String assetPath;

  @override
  _GameState createState() => _GameState();
}

class _GameState extends State<Game> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [
    [""]
  ];
  // int _listCount = 0;
  int _listCount = 0;
  bool _isFirstLoad = true;
  // String assetPath = "files/main.jpg";
  String assetPath = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    assetPath = widget.assetPath;
    _listCount = widget.listCount;
    _loadCSV();
  }

  // This function is only triggered at init, so we only load csv once
  void _loadCSV() async {
    String rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
    _listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(rawData);
    // assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == ""
    //     ? "files/main.jpg"
    //     : _listData[_listCount][1];
  }
///


  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
      // assetPath =
      // _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1];
      _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? null : _showAlertDialog();
      _saveData();
    });
  }


  //Saving my data
  Future<void> _saveData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      prefs.setInt('listCount', _listCount);
      prefs.setString('assetPath', assetPath);
      print(_listCount);
      print(assetPath);
    });
  }


  // This function makes buttons visible/invisible
  bool isVisible = true; //will be visible for the first frame

  void _isVisible() {
    setState(() {
      isVisible = !isVisible;
    });
  }


//Alert Dialog about questions and answers
  Widget _answer1TextButton(){
    return TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][3]),
      onPressed:  () {
        setState(() {
        assetPath = _listData[_listCount][6];
        _listCount = _listData[_listCount][2]-1;
        // _listData[_listCount][0];
        // _nextCSV();
        print('Answer 1');
        print(_listCount);
        Navigator.of(context).pop();  // Popping globalContext
          });
      },
    );
  }
  Widget _answer2TextButton(){
    return TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][5]),
      onPressed:  () {
        setState(() {
        assetPath = _listData[_listCount][7];
        _listCount = _listData[_listCount][4]-1;
        print('Answer 2');
        print(_listCount);
        Navigator.of(context).pop();  // Popping globalContext
        });
        },
    );
  }

  void _showAlertDialog() {

// set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      // title: Text(),
      content: Text(_listData[_listCount][1]),
      actions: [
        _answer1TextButton(),
        _answer2TextButton(),
      ],
    );

// show the dialog
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,  //use to dismiss any tap on the background of the dialog
      context: context,
      // useRootNavigator: false, //this property needs to be added
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return true;   // false to disable the back button
          },
          child: alert,
        );
      },
    );
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('New Game'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(assetPath),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Visibility(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Positioned.fill(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: AssetImage('files/sheet.jpg'),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(_listData[_listCount][0]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        ImageButton(label: 'OK', onButtonTap: _nextCSV),
                        ImageButton(label: 'Hide', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
                        ImageButton(label: 'Test1', onButtonTap: _showAlertDialog),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                visible: isVisible,
              ),
              // your other widgets
              Visibility(
                child: ImageButton(label: 'Show', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
                visible: !isVisible,
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1.** My answer to Prabhakaran:

1. It seems to me that my error is not related to the line:

```dart
_listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? null : _showAlertDialog();
```

I commented it out, but the problem is not gone. But you are right. It's because of _listData. This is just my guess, but I think the problem is code load order or something. I mean that at the time of transferring values from variables, _listData does not have time to receive data from the csv file and is an empty array. Of course, if my reasoning makes sense.

2. I corrected my code (about saving my data). Thank you.
3. I am attaching a screenshot of the error. As part of the experiment, I tried to pass any value other than zero. But even 1 causes such an error. However, the console directly says that only the value 0 should be here:

[image]

**Edit 2.** I use Android Studio. Here is more information about the error in the console. So here is what I have when I click on the Continue game button:

Run tab:

```dart
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following RangeError was thrown building Game(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _GameState#ef0b2):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 2

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Game Game:file:///D:/flutter%20projects/example/lib/main.dart:103:63
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
#1      _GameState.build (package:example/main.dart:344:41)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4806:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
...     Normal element mounting (275 frames)
#283    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:16)
#284    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6350:36)
#285    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#286    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5883:32)
#287    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
#288    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#289    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#290    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#291    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#292    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#293    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#294    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#295    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#296    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#297    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#298    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#299    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#300    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#301    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:108:11)
#302    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#303    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#304    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#305    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#306    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#307    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#308    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#309    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#310    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#311    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#312    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#313    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#314    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#315    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#316    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#317    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#318    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#319    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#320    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#321    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#322    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:891:21)
#323    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#324    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#325    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#326    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:997:5)
#330    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#331    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#332    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
```

Just in case, I ran Debug. Here's what's there:

```dart
static members of _GrowableList 
exception = {RangeError} RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 2
this = {_GrowableList} size = 1
 0 = {_GrowableList} size = 1
index = 2
```

**Edit3.** When I click on the OK button, this code should be called:

```dart
// This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
      _listData.asMap()[_listCount]?.asMap()[1] ?? "" == "" ? null : _showAlertDialog();
      _saveData();
    });
  }


// Saving my data
  Future<void> _saveData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('listCount', _listCount);
    prefs.setString('assetPath', assetPath);
    print(_listCount);
    print(assetPath);
  }
```

But I see this error in the console:

```dart
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

**Edit4.** I managed to get rid of this error. I returned the "old" line, which is responsible for calling the pop-up dialog. I don't know how correct this is, but it works now.

```dart
// This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
      // assetPath =
      // _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1];
      _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? null : _showAlertDialog();
      // _listData.asMap()[_listCount]?.asMap()[1] ?? "" == "" ? null : _showAlertDialog(); //temporary
      _saveData();
    });
  }
```

However, just now I noticed your valuable comment:

```dart
and also in load data once your data loaded, add setState for the value to get reflected
```

Indeed, now saving is not happening. Every time I click on Continue Game, I get the values for New Game.

There is already a setState here. What else should I add in order for the data to load?

```dart
//Loading my data
  Future<void> _loadData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _listCount = (prefs.getInt('listCount') ?? 0);
      assetPath = (prefs.getString('assetPath') ?? "images/01.jpg");
      print(_listCount);
      print(assetPath);
    });
  }
```

Because at the moment I have a rather strange situation. For the sake of experiment, I set the initial values ​​for New Game:

```dart
listCount: 3, assetPath: "images/03.jpg"
```

Then I do a few clicks on the button. The console shows that the current values ​​are:

```dart
listCount: 11, assetPath: "images/03.jpg"
```

I click on the back button, get to the main page and click on Continue Game, which should pass the saved values ​​like this:

```dart
listCount: _listCount, assetPath: assetPath
```

But instead, I see completely different values. The console shows:

```dart
listCount: 0, assetPath: "images/04.jpg"
```

Obviously, they remained in memory even before all these changes.

Comment: can you provide the error screenshot

Comment: Yes, I attached it to Edit1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As the error says "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 5", it has something to do with List items, not the Shared Preferences. The error has to be from the line

`_listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? null : _showAlertDialog();`

because _listData might not have many records we are trying to access via _listCount or in _answer2TextButton widget _listData[_listCount] the data may not be an array or it won't have 6 elements.

2. There is no need to setState for storing value in shared preferences.

```
// Saving my data
Future<void> _saveData() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setInt('listCount', _listCount);
  prefs.setString('assetPath', assetPath);
  print(_listCount);
  print(assetPath);
}
```

Comment: My answer turned out to be long, so I wrote it in Edit1.

Comment: what about the answer button widget I mentioned. check with static text

Comment: I commented out these widgets, the button and everything related to calling this popup. But the error persists.

Comment: kindly provide full details of the error. like error screenshot of ide

Comment: I am ready to provide any information. What kind of screenshot do you need? If that error is on a red background, then it is in my Edit1.

Comment: android studio or visual studio will show detailed error

Comment: In Edit 2 I have attached the logs of the Run and Debug tabs when clicking on the Continue Game button.

Comment: your _listData is loading but before that flutter will render the _listData[listCount][2].  So only error because during init _listData is [[""]].  So in Game file whenever you are accesing _listCount, try to use like this _listData.asMap()[_listCount]?.asMap()[1] ?? ""

Comment: and also in load data once your data loaded, add setState for the value to get reflected

Comment: Thank you. To be honest, I don't understand what exactly I should do. Should I put in _listData.asMap()[_listCount]?.asMap()[1] ?? "" before each mention of _listCount in the Game screen? For example, before _listCount = widget.listCount; and so on.

Comment: no where ever you are using _listData[_listCount][some number] use it like _listData.asMap()[_listCount]?.asMap()[some number] ?? "", hope the result is text. If the expected  _listData[_listCount][some number] is not text, use it like _listData.asMap()[_listCount]?.asMap()[some number] ?? 0 for number. like wise use accrodingly

Comment: I replaced all of them. As a result, the text and popup dialog do not appear when I click on the OK button, which should call _nextCSV, Instead, in the console, I get the error The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'. I posted in Edit3 what _nextCSV looks like now. Perhaps you can easily find the error there.

Comment: During the experiment, I eliminated this error. But I still have one question about loading data. This is related to your valuable comment about setState. I wrote about it in Edit4.

Comment: I mentioned for _loadCSV in the game widget which is not having the setState

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. By the way, I have found the reason why I have the wrong variable values loaded. This happens when I exit the game to the main menu and click "Continue Game" again. But if I turn off the application and turn it back on, then I get the correct values. That is, _loadData(); loaded only when the application is turned on. I added _loadData(); to the Continue Game button. I don't know how correct this is, but it works. Thanks again for your help. You are the best!